# How to take selective backup?

Tags: backup, cp

Say there is a folder called `domains` in `glassfish`. It has `domain1`, `domain2`...`domainN`.

I want to take everything from `domain1` except the `logs` directory and save them to `/home/user/backup` directory.

I can do this manually,

```
cp -R /home/user/glassfish/domains/domain1 /home/user/backup
rm -rf /home/user/backup/domain1/logs
```

But how can I do this more easily?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `rsync` instead of `cp`. Mostly the same for local-to-local copies except that there's an exclude option

```
rsync --archive --exclude /logs /home/user/glassfish/domains/domain1 /home/user/backup
```

Comment: I remember seeing someone do something like this( I forgot and history command didn't show it later). `cp -R  \`ls | grep -v logs\`  source destination `.

Comment: @achhainsan that won't work, but even if it did seem to work it will break if any of your files or directories contain a space in their name

Comment: ‘Mostly the same’ I would argue that `rsync` is far superior to `cp` for local copies when working with large numbers of files because it lets you restart incomplete copies without having to care whether the last file copied was copied fully, can do incremental copies without needing timestamps to match up logically, and can give you _much_ nicer progress information than `cp` can.

Comment: When I checked `cp` (and have just checked again), my GNU version 9,0 doesn't have an include/exclude option. I'm not surprised a newer version has these as it's an obvious enhancement, but my versions don't, @BlockchainOffice

Comment: @roaima what if I've to exclude multiple files?

Comment: there is no rsync in server and installation access isn't allowed.

Comment: @achhainsan multiple exclusions can be handled with multiple `--exclude` options

Comment: @achhainsan if you're not allowed to install `rsync` you have a couple of choices. (1) Intel it in your own directory; it's an unprivileged app so this is perfectly possible. (2) submit a request to your change board asking them to install it on your behalf

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that rsync has `--exclude-from`, which allows you to save your exclude/include list in a file. Great for longer filter lists and prone against mistyping/forgetting directories across commands.

Comment: @achhainsan - rsync just needs a binary to be present on the server - somewhere in the `$PATH`, even a user directory is fine. You can download the binaries from https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/binaries/

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `cp` command and exclude the folder with the logs, with `!(excluded_folder)` if you don't want to use `rsync` or `tar`

```
cp -var /home/user/glassfish/domains/domain1/!(/home/user/backup/domain1/logs) /home/user/backup
```

or

```
cp -R /home/user/glassfish/domains/domain1/!(/home/user/backup/domain1/logs) /home/user/backup
```

If you want to exclude more folders you can use the `|` like
`!(excluded_folder1|excluded_folder2|excluded_folder3)`

Make sure that your shell supports extended pattern matching (e.g., Bash with the `extglob` option enabled).

If you want to use it in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
cp -var /home/user/glassfish/domains/domain1/!(/home/user/backup/domain1/logs) /home/user/backup
```

If you receive error something like `!": event not found"`

Check this post:

[What is "-bash: !": event not found"](https://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found)

Comment: you should surround your parameters: `/home.....logs)` by a singlequote: `'/home/.....logs)'` , or if using bash in interactive mode, do before a : `set +o histexpand`. This will make the use of a `!` safer in general (otherwise in many cases bash will see it as the history substitution command and will try to replace : `!foo` with whatever matches `foo` in the current history, before running the resulting command-line)

Comment: This didn't work on server. Was producing something like ! not an event.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` or `tar` to make archived copy:

```
cd /home/user/glassfish/domains/domain1
tar --exclude="logs" cvf /home/user/backup/domain1.tar .
```

and so on. Or with `zip`:

```
cd /home/user/glassfish/domains/domain1
zip /home/user/backup/domain1.zip  -x logs/**\* .
```

This way you have the advantage of naming archives based on date so you can keep history of records there.

Comment: coincidentally, using tar or cpio to copy lots of files is faster than `cp` - just tar to stdout and pipe that into a `tar -xf -`

Comment: @symcbean, why to extract? IMHO for backup is much better to have more than one copy of the information. Also this have a benefit `zip` compress the information (`tar` can do this with external libraries)

Comment: to replicate the behaviour the OP describes, yes, you'd need to extract the data. This could devolve into a long discussion about data integrity and backups, but using tar with compression is far from ideal for backup pruposes (and so is copying files to the local filesystem)..

Answer (score 2):

If you can't rely on shell syntax you can resort to `find` and `cpio` in pass-through mode:

```sh
find SOURCE \( -depth 1 -name logs -prune \) -o \( -type f -print0 \) |
cpio -p -v -0 -d DESTINATION
```

The following `cpio` options might be of further interest (if your implementation supports them):

> - `-a`, `--reset-access-time` – Reset access times on files after they are read.
> - `-m`, `--preserve-modification-time` – Set file modification time on created files to match those in the source.
> - `--no-preserve-owner` – Do not attempt to restore file ownership.  This is the default when run by non-root users.
> - `-R [user][:][group]`, `--owner [user][:][group]` – Set the owner and/or group on files in the output. [...] this option can only be used by the super-user.
> - `-u`, `--unconditional` – Unconditionally overwrite existing files.  Ordinarily, an older file will not overwrite a newer file on disk.